# Undefined index: in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-4

this is my code ..hope you guys help me because i want to get the value of country['CC_FIPS'] to use in my where statement in city

```
    $local = Input::get('locality');
    $country = Input::get('country');
    $resultCountry= Country::where('COUNTRY_NAME', '=', $country)->get();

    //echo $resultCountry;
    $resultCity= City::where('FULL_NAME_ND', '=', $local)
            ->where('CC_FIPS', '=', $resultCountry['CC_FIPS'])
                ->get();
        }

    echo $resultCity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you array  $resultCountry does not have any element with index CC_FIPS.

You can see what elements are in this array if you use function dd() as

```
dd($resultCountry);
```

Comment: @thank sir margus for the info but i already fix it by using foreach  :)

Comment: Perfect! If you found the solution then you can accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $local = Input::get('locality');
    $country = Input::get('country');
    $resultCountry= Country::where('COUNTRY_NAME', '=', $country)->first()->toArray();

    //echo $resultCountry;
    $resultCity= City::where('FULL_NAME_ND', '=', $local)
            ->where('CC_FIPS', '=', $resultCountry['CC_FIPS'])
                ->get();
        }

    print_r($resultCity);
```

Instead of get use first and keep the rest t=of the code as it is.. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

```
 $local = Input::get('locality');
    $country = Input::get('country');
    $resultCountry= Country::where('COUNTRY_NAME', '=', $country)->first();

    //echo $resultCountry;
    $resultCity= City::where('FULL_NAME_ND', '=', $local)
            ->where('CC_FIPS', '=', $resultCountry['CC_FIPS'])
                ->get();
        }

    print_r($resultCity);
```

When Using Get in your first query The result will be returned something like this..

```
[
   [0]=>[
        ]
]
```

So instead of Get Use first which will get only one array
Also on the second query you cannot echo the result you need to print_r it

Answer (score 0):

You can convert $resultCountry to an array like this :

```
$resultCountry= Country::where('COUNTRY_NAME', '=', $country)->get()->toArray();
```

then $resultCountry['CC_FIPS'] should return your value properly.